# How do I run my flutter app in dart v2 mode in debug in VS Code (--preview-dart-2 option)

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

In the command line I can use

```
flutter run `--preview-dart-2`
```

and this runs the program using the v2 or dart.  How do I add this option in the debug mode of flutter from vs code?

Comment: dart-2 is by default enabled if you are on v0.2.5 and above

Comment: Thats strange, if I do a flutter run --preview-dart-2 redux works, if I don't do that I get an error saying I need to enable dart2

Comment: Not sure why that might happen, you can check the change log of flutter versions [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Changelog#v024).

Comment: Try upgrading flutter to newer version. Note: Before upgrading check for the changelog and ensure no breaking changes that affects you code.

Comment: I get the same error (the error I get when I exclude the --preview-dart-2 option) if I run in debug mode from vs code.  I wonder if all dart 2 features are enabled?

Comment: Yes, I have upgraded (if I try again it says 'already up-to-date'

Comment: 0.2.3 is the latest for now on beta branch. Consider switching to master which is at a much higher version (0.2.10 if I'm correct).

Comment: Thanks Remi, I'll try the later version. Its strange though that I'm getting different results with the preview dart 2 flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings of visual studio code there is a flag for enabling dart 2 which specifies that it should be sending --preview-dart-2:

```
// Whether to enable previewing Dart 2.0 functionality such as optional new/const. 
// true: send --preview-dart-2
// false: send --no-preview-dart-2
// undefined: do not send a flag
  "dart.previewDart2": null
```